# How to extract interesting piece of output in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, regex

My output of command is like:

```
File Size                       : 23 kB
File Size                       : 9.8 kB
File Size                       : 9 kB
File Size                       : 128 kB
File Size                       : 921.8 kB
```

How to extract from this to this:

```
23kB
9.8kB
9kB
128kB
921.8kB
```

I tried to use sed with command

```
sed 's/^..................................//'
```

output is

```
23 kB
9.8 kB
9 kB
128 kB
921.8 kB
```

and in this point my knowledge about sed and regex is end.
How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove everything before a colon, and to remove all spaces:

```
sed 's/.*://; s/ //g' file
```

The first substitution replaces `.*:`, i.e. anything up to the last colon, with nothing. The second substitution replaces space with nothing globally.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `cut` instead of `sed`:

Set the delimiter to colon and choose second field:

```
cut -d ':' -f 2 file
```

Output:

```
 23 kB
 9.8 kB
 9 kB
 128 kB
 921.8 kB
```

Then remove the spaces with `tr -d`:

```
cut -d ':' -f 2 file | tr -d ' '
```

Output:

```
23kB
9.8kB
9kB
128kB
921.8kB
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain separate replacements:

```
's/^.*: //; s/ //'
```

But parsing verbose commands like that is always a bit chonky and unreliable. I would suggest something like find (with whatever filters you need) and chaining that into `stat`, like this:

```
find . -exec stat --printf="%s\n" {} +
```

See `man stat` for more options on output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F\: '{gsub(/ /, ""); print $2}'
```

This will use `:` as a delimiter, remove all spaces, and print the second column.